# Only half a triangle shows when rotating in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to rotate a triangle around the the Y axis.  When I rotate it about the Z axis, everything is fine.  But when I try rotating about the Y axis, all I get is a half triangle, rotating about the Y axis.  I'm using PowerVRs OpenGL ES 2.0 SDK. My Init and Draw functions are below.

```
int Init(ESContext* esContext)
{
    UserData* userData = (UserData *)esContext->userData;
    const char *vShaderStr =
        "attribute vec4 vPosition;  \n"
        "uniform mat4 MVPMatrix;"
        "void main()                \n"
        "{                          \n"
        "   gl_Position = MVPMatrix * vPosition;\n"
        "}                          \n";

    const char *fShaderStr =
        "precision mediump float;   \n"
        "void main()                \n"
        "{                          \n"
        "   gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); \n"
        "}                          \n";

    GLuint vertexShader;
    GLuint fragmentShader;
    GLuint programObject;
    GLint linked;
    GLfloat ratio = 320.0f/240.0f;

    vertexShader = LoadShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vShaderStr);
    fragmentShader = LoadShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fShaderStr);

    programObject = glCreateProgram();

    if (programObject == 0)
        return 0;

    glAttachShader(programObject, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(programObject, fragmentShader);

    glBindAttribLocation(programObject, 0, "vPosition");
    glLinkProgram(programObject);
    glGetProgramiv(programObject, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &linked);

    if (!linked)
    {
        GLint infoLen = 0;
        glGetProgramiv(programObject, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLen);

        if (infoLen > 1)
        {
            char* infoLog = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * infoLen);
            glGetProgramInfoLog(programObject, infoLen, NULL, infoLog);

            free(infoLog);
        }

        glDeleteProgram(programObject);
        return FALSE;
    }

    userData->programObject = programObject;

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    glViewport(0, 0, esContext->width, esContext->height);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    glUseProgram(userData->programObject);

    userData->angle = 0.0f;
    userData->start = time(NULL);
    userData->ProjMatrix = PVRTMat4::Perspective(ratio*2.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 7.0f, PVRTMat4::eClipspace::OGL, false, false);
    userData->ViewMatrix = PVRTMat4::LookAtLH(PVRTVec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f), PVRTVec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), PVRTVec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    return TRUE;
}



void Draw(ESContext *esContext)
{
    GLfloat vVertices[] = {0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
                          -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                           0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f};

    GLint MVPHandle;
    double timelapse;

    PVRTMat4 MVPMatrix = PVRTMat4::Identity();
    UserData* userData = (UserData *)esContext->userData;

    timelapse = difftime(time(NULL), userData->start) * 1000;
    if(timelapse > 16.0f) //Maintain approx 60FPS
    {
        if (userData->angle > 360.0f)
        {
            userData->angle = 0.0f;
        }
        else
        {
            userData->angle += 0.1f;
        }
    }

    userData->ModelMatrix = PVRTMat4::RotationY(userData->angle);

    MVPMatrix = userData->ViewMatrix * userData->ModelMatrix;
    MVPMatrix = userData->ProjMatrix * MVPMatrix;

    MVPHandle = glGetUniformLocation(userData->programObject, "MVPMatrix");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MVPHandle, 1, FALSE, MVPMatrix.ptr());

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vVertices);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    eglSwapBuffers(esContext->eglDisplay, esContext->eglSurface);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PVRTMat4::Perspective(ratio*2.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 7.0f, PVRTMat4::eClipspace::OGL, false, false);` puts the near clipping plane at `3.0f` units away from the camera (via [the third argument](https://netst.org/pub/linux/ARM/OMAP/TI/Graphics_SDK_4_03_00_02/GFX_Linux_SDK/OVG/SDKPackage/Tools/Documentation/html/structPVRTMat4.html#e14)).

`PVRTMat4::LookAtLH(PVRTVec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f), PVRTVec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), PVRTVec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));` places the camera at (0, 0, -3), looking back at (0, 0, 0).

You generate a model matrix directly using `PVRTMat4::RotationY(userData->angle);` so that matrix does no translation. The triangle you're drawing remains positioned on (0, 0, 0) as per its geometry.

So what's happening is that the parts of the triangle that get closer to the camera than 3 units are being clipped by the near clipping plane. The purpose of the near clipping plane is effectively to place the lens of the camera relative to where the image will be perceived. Or it's like specifying the distance from user to screen, if you prefer.

You therefore want either to bring the near clip plane closer to the camera or to move the camera further away from the triangle.